# Are there any infinite series of the same form which converge to the same number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know of course that there are some numbers for x and a make this statement true

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (5x)^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (a)^i$$
but if it where
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (x)^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (a)^i$$
the only number x could be would be a. correct?

If so is this true for all infinite series?
If not, is there a way to identify if series falls into that grope?

Comment: In $\sum x^{2i}$ you can always replace $x$ with $-x$. In $\sum (\sin x)^i$, you can replace $x$ with $x+2\pi$. Incidentally, in $\sum\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!}x^{2i+1}$, you can also replace $x$ with $x+2\pi$.

Comment: cool thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{i+2} = \frac{x^2}{1-x}$$
This series converges for all $x\in(-1,1)$. But the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x}$ is not single-valued in that interval (because $f(0)=0$, but $f(x)\ge 0$ everywhere). So there are distinct $x,y\in (-1,1)$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: I think that makes sense to me. so the infinite series for y of that function must have 2 or more values for a given x.

Comment: @TonyK You'd certainly need some comment about continuity in there ("$f(x)=0$, but $f(x)\geq 0$ everywhere" doesn't really tell you anything in regard to the OPs question).


But yes, $f$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$, $f(0)=0$, and $f(-1/ 2),f(1/ 2) > 0$. By the intermediate values theorem the range of $f$ on $[-1/ 2,0]$ contains $[0, f(-1/ 2)]$. Similarly the range of $f$ on $[0,1/ 2]$ contains $[0, f(1/ 2)]$. So every value of $f$ in $[0,f(-1/ 2)]\cap [0,f(1/ 2)]$ must be obtained twice (once in $[-1/ 2, 0]$ and once in $[0,1/ 2]$).

Comment: @adfriedman: sometimes it's best to let people fill these details in for themselves. (Oh, and "every value...must be obtained twice" is clearly wrong.)

Comment: @TonyK ...with the single exception of $0$. Fine: Every value of $f$ in $(0,\min\{f(-1/ 2),f(1/ 2)\})$ is obtained twice. A trivial observation about the second derivative also gives that they are obtained exactly twice.

Comment: Or, of course, setting
$$\frac{x^2}{1-x} = y,\implies x=\frac{-y \pm \sqrt{y(y+4)}}{2}$$
which may be shown to satisfy the criteria.